# DropDownList changes of width when an input is focused

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

My DropDownList won't keep the size setted in the CSS.

When the input is focused, the size is larger than expected.

Otherwize, the size is good.

[image]

What should I do for keeping the size of the DropDownList at the good size even if the input is focused ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are your current styles for the DropDownList?

Comment: width: 100%;
font-size: 1.1em;
height: 25px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

Comment: Works fine in IE 11 in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7vLmgy6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this: onmousedown="$(this).focus()"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css `:focus`

```
input:focus { 
   //set the style the same as your input while not focused
}
```

Comment: i am interrested in the style of the DropDownList, not the style of the input

Comment: then it would be `select:focus`. An asp.net DropDownList is just a basic HTML `select`